# Check box inside a ListView, setChecked(true) is not working in Nougat

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have `ListView` of each item with `text view` and a `check box`

when clicking on each item I'm changing the check box state true/false to display selected items in a list.

```
 listSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Helper.hideKeyBoard(getApplicationContext(), view);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox_value);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
       checkBox.setChecked(false);
       }
    else{
       checkBox.setChecked(true);                           
     }
     }

    });
```

I tried using runaable also :

```
 checkBox.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        });
```

it is working on Marshmallow correctly but not working on Nougat!

Note : when I click on the second item the first item tick is showing in nougat.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @gprathour I think I explained in the question, When I click on item in the listview that item check box should get ticked. when I run in marshmallow the check box is getting ticked, but in nougat it didn't! am I clear

Comment: I didn't get this thing, if(checkBox.isChecked) then checkBox.setChecked(false);

Comment: @gprathour when using checkBox to show the state we use `isChecked` it will return whether the checkBox is checked or not, when on click if it is already checked we are uncheck it.

Comment: have you maintaining checkbox state in adapter if not you have to maintain it using data set variable  for differentiate checked or not show adapter code i think problem is here recycling of view

Comment: @Pavan yeah I'm posting my adapter code wait

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to display list of selected items u need to maintain checkbox state

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution to this issue if you are still facing :

Replace your below code :

```
checkBox.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        });
```

To my code & see if it works:

```
checkBox.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                                checkBox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your code is going like this:

You are clicking a checkbox -> it detects it is clicked and it check itself -> You are checking is it is checked or not -> If its checked then you are using setChecked(false) which unchecks your checkbox.

Remove following code and it should work:

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
       checkBox.setChecked(false);
       }
    else{
       checkBox.setChecked(true);                           
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this listener to check if a checkbox is selected or not and do an action correspondingly.

```
checkBox setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

           }
       }
    );
```